# MOOC dataset with opening and removal dates

Tags: data-request, mooc

I am looking for a dataset on MOOC availability, including as many following fields as possible:

- MOOC title
- MOOC platform
- opening date
- registration closing date (i.e., date after which new student cannot enroll into the course)
- [removal date](https://www.class-central.com/report/coursera-old-platform-shutdown-download-courses/) (i.e., date after which nobody can access the course materials)

I am mostly interested in removal dates, and it particular in the list of Coursera courses that will be removed during the [June 30 clean-up](https://blog.coursera.org/post/145882467032).